# Jquery .get not retrieving file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code that is supposed to read from a html file, split it into an array and display parts of that array, but when going though with alert, i found that $.get is not actually getting the file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">update</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>    
        function myfunction() {    
            var info = "";
            $.get("../Read_Test/text.html", function(data) {
                SomeFunction(data);
            });

            alert(info);

            var array = info.split("§n");
            var people = array[1].split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = people[i] + "<br>";
            }
        }
        function SomeFunction(data) {
            var info = data;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the directories are on a server and go like so:
Sublinks->Read_Test->This_File.html,text.html
The objective of this is that a file would have something along the lines of "a§nb1,b2,b3,§n" and the script would split it via "§n" then get "array[1]" and split that via ",". lastly it displays each part of that newly created array on a new line, so a file with "a§nb1,b2,b3,§n" would result in:
`b1
b2 
b3`
Please help

Comment: You are aware that your variable `info` actually are 2 different variables, aren't you? One in each function (declared with `var`).

Comment: SomeFunction does nothing useful.

Comment: `SomeFunction` is just creating a new variable `info` and putting the `data` into it. But this `info` is not the same you have in `myFunction`, which is always blank.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is **asynchronous**, it make request and immediately call the next instruction and not wait for the response from the ajax request. so you will need to process inside of `$.get`. success event.

I have changed delimiter character to ¥. change same in text.html. problem was you have not mentioned character set to utf8 and due to this it could not recognized the special character and subsequently not able to split the string. i have aldo document type to HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">update</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>    

        function myfunction() {    
            $.get("../Read_Test/text.html", function(data) {
                var info = data;
                var array = info.split("¥");
                var people = array[1].split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += people[i] + "<br>";
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just doing `<script>
function myfunction() {
$.get("../Read_Test/text.html", function(data) {  
    var info = data;  
    var array = info.split("§n");  
    var people = array[1].split(",");  
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {  
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = people[i] + "<br>";  
    }  
});  
}  
</script>`  
will work?

Comment: I just tried what Rashmin Javiya said, and i got the the error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, meaning $.get is still not reading the file?

Comment: it seems ajax could not get file content successfully. could you check  ajax bring the content of html file in Network window of developer tool

Comment: it says: Name:text.html, method:get, status:200, type:text/html, initiator: jquery.min.js:4, size: 181 B, time:284ms

Comment: no not jquery, there should be "text.html", check the response of the same

Comment: i don't understand? what do you want me to check?

Comment: i have it on my site, if you want to check for yourself? http://bobdinator.netai.net/Sublinks/Read_Test/

Comment: § character creating problem, it is not splitting the text, could you use another character?

Comment: i need a character which someone is unlikely to use if chatting?

Comment: changed it from "§n" to "/\" and still doesn't workl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54798/discussion-between-rashmin-javiya-and-user3680619).

Comment: You're still using `var info` twice.

Comment: Why don't you use json as a data storage structure instead of your delimited list?? or XML even? both are capable of storing chat messages far more effectively than a delimited list.